# Azure media player show poster and hide controls

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am using Azure media player in my web app and I am trying to get it to do 3 things:

1. Show a poster (this works)
2. Hide the controls at the bottom of the screen when the poster is showing
3. Add a big play button centered on the poster.

I cant seem to figure out how to do steps 2 and 3. I see a class in the examples called `amp-big-play-centered` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is what it looks like right now when the page loads. autoplay is off:
[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
 <video poster="marketingSplash.png" src="video.mp4" id="vplayer" class="azuremediaplayer  amp-default-skin  amp-big-play-centered embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" controls>
```

Comment: Please post more code - because so far that's just your `<video>` element. What scripts are you loading? Any stylesheets?

Comment: ah, thanks for that. Brain fart. I wasn't actually initializing the player. Everything is working now.

Comment: To help others, could you please share your solution in the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer shared in comment as below:

The issue was resovled by initializing the player. 
@Chris, feel free to provide more details if any.